# JavaScript alert popup box not being called

Tags: javascript, concurrency, popupwindow, django-1.11

I'm completely new to JavaScript and am trying to implement a popup box upon concurrency editing in Django. I've tried using the `popUp` function in js but to no avail. Here's my code

**html**

```
{% block content %}
  <div class="page-header">
    {% if is_editable %}
      <div>
        Got to here
      </div>

      <!--{% block custom_js %}
      <script src="{% static "myapp/form_edit.popup.js" %} type="text/javascript"></script>
      {% endblock custom_js %}-->

      <script language="JavaScript">
      function popUp() {
        alert("Be careful!");
      }
      </script>


    {% endif %}
```

**js**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function popUp() {
    alert("try to be careful!");
}
</script>
```

As can be seen the original intention was just to call a simple js script which produces the popup. This didn't work. So then I simply embedded the js code in the html, and this okay. The line `Got to here` is just to test if my `if` clause is actually triggered, which it is as the text is shown on my page. How can I get the code from the .js file to be triggered?

Comment: where is popUp()  called?

Answer (score 2):

Where are you actually calling `popUp()`?

Try:

```
var popUp = function popUp() {
   alert("Be careful!");
};
popUp();
```